What's the difference between "outlet" and "chain store"?
As I looked up in some dictionaries, "they said "outlets" and "chain stores" both refer to stores that only sell products of one company. Outlets often offer big discounts, and chain stores sell products at retail prices.
But I heard about 7-Eleven outlets and chain stores of Walmart (7-Eleven and Walmart sell several products of several brands), so I'm quite confused about this.

An outlet is operated by one company, and sells only products or brands made by that company. A chain store is one of a number of similar stores operated by one company and sells different brands made by different companies.

@MichaelHarvey here there's plenty of "outlets", particularly clothing ones, that sell overstock or clearance from multiple brands - what Wikipedia suggests would be a closeout store in English-speaking countries. Are they not referred to as such in the US/UK?

In the UK, ''closeout stores' are usually called 'clearance stores'. A well known chain of them is called Matalan, and another is TK Maxx

In American English, a discount outlet can be a  store that buys up random odd lots and overstock and sells the merchandise at a discount, retail not wholesale.  7-11 is not called an "outlet" in the US but a "convenience store".  But there is a phrase "retail outlets" that would  refer to what are not "outlets" that sell overstock but chain stores that sell at standard retail prices (with periodic sales).

No, @MaciejStachowski, here in the US I have never encountered closeout store. It may be used in the retail industry, but it’s not at all idiomatic in communication with or between the customers.

@MichaelHarvey, really? *TK Maxx? Here in the US it’s TJ Maxx.

@PaulTanenbaum it is TK Maxx outside of US, including here. Apparently there's some other retailer in the UK that uses a similar name.

@PaulTanenbaum - When the company opened stores in the UK in 1994, it used the name TK Maxx to avoid confusion with TJ Hughes, a British retail chain. It carried on with the name TK Maxx elsewhere in Europe when it expanded there.

You get the max for the minimum at TJ Maxx. It's never ever the same store twice. .

"outlet" can be basically a synonym for "store". The dictionary will show there are slightly differing definitions of that word. This usage wouldn't be very common though either. There's no overlap in meaning with chain stores though. An "outlet" can also sell clearance items (a slightly different usage) but even that is distinct from a "discount store".
